# Como remover as horas de uma string DateTime

Tags: javascript, data, datetime, formatação

Estou puxando um registro datetime do meu Banco de Dados e estou formatando ela para o formato tradicional brasileiro, no entanto, não consigo retirar as horas depois do último valor, sempre repete a hora. A minha função é esta;

```
const formatarData = (data) =>{
    var arrayData = data.split('-');
    var dataCorreta = `${arrayData[2]}/${arrayData[1]}/${arrayData[0]}`;
    return dataCorreta;
}
```

Entranto, o resultado que sai na formatação é este:

[image: Função para Formatação]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe que você utilizou a função Split especificando o delimitador "-" na String "2020-07-06 15:00:00".

Dessa forma você obteve 3 Strings:

```
arrayData[0] = "2020"
arrayData[1] = "07"
arrayData[2] = "06 15:00:00"
```

É interessante, nesse caso que primeiro você utilize a função Split com o delimitador " " (caracter espaço) para já inicialmente separar hora da data. E numa segunda etapa utilize novamente a função split para separar dia, mês e ano.

Exemplo:

```
var arrayDataHora = date.split(" ");
var arrayData = arrayDataHora[0].split("-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível solução é utilizar a classe `Date`:

```js
const formatarData = (data) =>{
    let d = new Date(data);
    // Month retorna entre 0 e 11, por isso a adição +1
    return `${d.getDate()}/${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getFullYear()}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dataFormatada(dataBanco){
    let data = new Date(dataBanco),
        dia  = data.getDate().toString(),
        diaF = (dia.length == 1) ? '0'+dia : dia,
        mes  = (data.getMonth()+1).toString(), //+1 pois no getMonth Janeiro começa com zero.
        mesF = (mes.length == 1) ? '0'+mes : mes,
        anoF = data.getFullYear();
    
    // return diaF+"/"+mesF+"/"+anoF;

    console.log(diaF+"/"+mesF+"/"+anoF);
}

/* ###### data vindo do banco exemplo com PHP
    dataBanco="<?php echo $dataBanco ?>";
########################################### */

dataBanco="2020-07-06 15:00:00";

//chamada da função
dataFormatada(dataBanco);
```

A tarefa da instrução `new Date( )` é criar um local na memória para todos os dados que uma data precisa armazenar.

```js
console.log(new Date("2020-07-06 15:00:00"));
```

O método `getDate()` retorna o dia do mês

O método `toString()` converte um objeto Date em uma string

```js
let data = new Date("2020-07-06 15:00:00")

console.log(data.getDate().toString());
```

`getMonth()` - mês dentro do ano (janeiro = 0)

`getFullYear()` - retorna o ano da data especificada de acordo com a hora local

**De posse desse dados você constrói a sua data da forma que desejar**

```
(diaF+"/"+mesF+"/"+anoF)

(anoF+"/"+mesF+"/"+diaF)
```